# Concatenate two functions into one in C

Tags: c, function, concatenation

How can I concatenate (or merge) two functions that take no arguments and return nothing into one function? In JavaScript I would do this:

```
function f1() {
    console.log("f1 called");
}
function f2() {
    console.log("f2 called");
}
function function_concat(fa, fb) {
    var final = function() {
        fa();
        fb();
    };
    return final;
}
var merged = function_concat(fa, fb);
merged();
```

In C, this is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*fptr)(void);
void f1() {
    printf("f1 called");
}
void f2() {
    printf("f2 called");
}

fptr function_concat(fa, fb) {
    // What to do here??
}
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    fptr merged = function_concat(f1, f2);
    fptr();
}
```

I know I'll have to return a static pointer, but I can't define a function in a function in C which makes it hard to create new functions if I'm already in a function. Does anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: In C, you cannot pass functions around in the same way as you would pass around variables and such. JavaScript and C support different programming paradigms. You'd probably have to do something a bit more involved if you insist on doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define function at runtime in C, so you're only option is to implement some sort of proxy. You can use global variables to refer to the function pointers, but to give an implicit answer, you can't really emulate this in C.

If you ever need to change the interface of `fa_` and `fb_` you'll need to call `function_concat` again, or set the global variables directly, but at that point you wouldn't need the proxy function.

```
static fptr fa_, fb_;

void function_concat_proxy() {
    fa_();
    fb_();
}

fptr function_concat(fptr fa, fptr fb) {
    fa_ = fp;
    fb_ = fb;
    return function_concat_proxy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface by saying that trying to emulate the behavior of a language which treats functions as first class citizens is a, to say the least, weird request.

Alternatively, one thing you could create a new `typedef` for a type that takes two function pointers and then call it:

```
typedef void (*mptr)(fptr, fptr);
```

With `function_concat` looking like:

```
void function_concat(fptr fa, fptr fb) {
    fa();
    fb();
}
```

and `main`:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    mptr merged = function_concat;
    merged(f1, f2);
}
```

Which is similar to just calling `function_concat(f1, f2)` only via a function pointer now. Apparently not exactly what you're looking for but, alas, I'll leave it here for reference.

Comment: Interesting solution, but I think the OP wants to set the function pointers themselves so that the returned function doesn't need to have arguments passed in.

Comment: Ah I see, just saw your answer too, I'll upvote and leave this here for reference. :-)

Comment: This does match the requirements of OP's code example. The functions all take no arguments.  If OP has further requirements then it'd be good for OP to update the question

Comment: @M.M The issue has nothing to do with arguments. The problem is the JS function `function_concat` *returns* a function that calls the two functions in question at some later time. This `function_concat` calls them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in c. What you can do is to call your 2 functions in the function_concat :

```
void function_concat(fa, fb) {
    fa();
    fb();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm very late, but for everyone who needs it, you can do this in c, however it's platform specific. Basically you allocate executable memory, modify binary program, load program to executable memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef void void_ft(void);

void_ft* fcat(void_ft x, void_ft y) {
    char op[] = "\x48\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xd0\x48\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xd0\xc3"; // program binary with zeros as blank slates to insert function pointers
    void_ft *r = mmap(NULL, 25, PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0); // allocate executable memory for program
    if (r == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate executable memory: %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    *(uint64_t*)(&op[2]) = (uint64_t)x; // set zeros to function pointers
    *(uint64_t*)(&op[14]) = (uint64_t)y;
    memcpy(r, op, 25); // copy new program with custom functions to executable memory
    return r;
}

void x(void) {
    printf("Hello ");
}

void y(void) {
    printf("World!\n");
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    void_ft *z = fcat(x, y);
    z();
    munmap(z, 25); //free executable memory
    return 0;
}
```

sorry for bad code :3